# Go loop indices for range on slice

Tags: loops, go, slice, indices

I have a fairly simple question, but can't find answer anywhere. I'm iterating over a range of slices, like this:

```
for index, arg := range os.Args[1:] {
    s += fmt.Sprintf("%d: %s", index, arg)
}
```

As I understand `range` iterates over a slice, and `index` is created from range, and it's zero-based. I get the output:

```
0: argument_1
1: argument_2
// etc.
```

But it's not what I expect - I need `range` to preserve indices of that slice, so my output looks like this:

```
1: argument_1
2: argument_2
// etc.
```

The most obvious way to achieve this is to add `shift` on index in loop:

```
shift := 1
for index, arg := range os.Args[shift:] {
    index += shift
    s += fmt.Sprintf("%d: %s", index, arg)
}
```

But I was wondering, is there more "Go-ish" way to do this, and also, how to preserve indices when creating a slice in Go like this?

Comment: In your `shift` example you are adding 1 to the index each time in addition to the usual increment of the for loop. Wouldn't this resolve in reading only arguments 1, 3, 5, etc ?

Comment: @MateiRadu No, index is reassigned for every loop so the code works. It would probably look better with a new variable like `originalIndex := index + 1` though

Comment: @FranckJeannin Thanks for the explanation, it cleared my doubts on how `range` works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your original code, when you are doing `os.Args[1:]` you are creating a new slice which like any slice starts at index 0.
It's a matter of style (and performance) but you could also do this:

```
for index, arg := range os.Args {
    if index < 1 {
        continue
    }
    s += fmt.Sprintf("%d: %s", index, arg)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering!